# Jquery each function on server

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with each function
i would like to change the link attribute href which has class .myclass without living the page on click
but the code works on localhsot but not on server 
my code:

```
$("a[class='holder_notify_drop_link']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var attr_href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('onClick', "openFrame('" + attr_href + "','yes')");
    });
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: there are no errors, i have tested the function by adding an alert test but it didn't work

Comment: You are probably calling your javascript before the page is loaded. Put it at the bottom of the page, or wrap it in `$(document).ready()` function, and see where does that get you.

Comment: You can't (or at least, shouldn't) add `onClick` attributes dynamically and expect them to run. That's what `.click()` is for.

Comment: Your selector is odd. Usually when selecting by class, you'd use: `$("a.holder_notify_drop_link")`. That said, what you specified should work, so that probably isn't causing your problem.

Comment: i wrapped it in $(document).ready() function

Answer (score 1):

That is totally wrong approach. Read about events here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

You would need to do something like:

```
$(".holder_notify_drop_link").on('click', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  openFrame(url,'yes');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Something like this should work for you, but you really need to read on jQuery and event binding.

Comment: i have to add onClick() attribute to my link

Comment: As I see from your code, you are adding onClick when you click on the <a> element? Are you sure that is really a requirement?

Comment: In fact, My aim is to read o message or, a notification or an invitation on my social network without living the current page.
how to do that ?